# How do you add server names to an array?

Tags: powershell

I’m sorta new to Powershell and am learning a lot from  “Powershell for SysAdmins” and came across the below I have questions about.

I see that the following is creating an array but if I wanted to add actual server names into it, do I edit “SRV1, SRV2,etc” or do I add them into `$($servers[0])` etc? If later, would it look like `$(\\servername[0])`?

```
$servers = @('SRV1','SRV2','SRV3','SRV4','SRV5')
Get-Content -Path "\\$($servers[0])\c$\App_configuration.txt"
Get-Content -Path "\\$($servers[1])\c$\App_configuration.txt"
Get-Content -Path "\\$($servers[2])\c$\App_configuration.txt"
Get-Content -Path "\\$($servers[3])\c$\App_configuration.txt"
Get-Content -Path "\\$($servers[4])\c$\App_configuration.txt"
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Like @mkelement0 said, you should format you post for better support.

But if i have to guess what you mean: You need to put the actual server names into the array above. Where the array is definded. 
Later the variables for example $servers[0] will get the values out of the array into the Get-Content cmdlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you found that example, but the whole point of pushing N server names into a single array is that you don't then have to repeat the same code N times - you can simply loop over the values in the array and repeat whatever operation you need to execute:

```
# edit this statement and replace the names with your real server names
$server = @('actualServerNameGoesHere01','actualServerNameGoesHere02','actualServerNameGoesHere03')

$server |ForEach-Object {
    # This statement will be executed for each of the names in `$servers`
    Get-Content -Path "\\$_\c$\App_configuration.txt"
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is much easier to read. Thanks!